# Timeout in Production but not in Local Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms, timeout

I am developing a Rails application.

In a view, I made a form which action is sent to a controller in AJAX by using `remote: true`

```
<%= form_tag({controller: "my_controller", action: "my_method"}, {remote: true}) do %>
```

Every thing works fine, but the controller can take a while to compute de result (sometimes more than 100 seconds).

The problem I am facing is that in local environment it works fine, but in production environment, I am getting **ERROR 504 GATEWAY_TIMEOUT**

Is there a way to make it work in production ?

Comment: You should probably put that function behind a background job using something like sidekiq or delayed_job. That's their whole purpose.

Comment: What is your server stack on production?

Comment: It's a Puma + Nginx + PostgreSQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely due to your load balancer (possibly apache or nginx) in front of your rails server timing out the response because it's taking so long!  I'm most familiar w/ Nginx so I'll walk you through the fix there.

---

If you set the response timeouts to 10 minutes (600 seconds) in nginx.conf:

```
proxy_connect_timeout       600;
proxy_send_timeout          600;
proxy_read_timeout          600;
send_timeout                600;
```

Then restart nginx with `service nginx reload` you should not see the 504s anymore :)

Answer (score 0):

Is your production Heroku? You need to get this into a background job. As a rule of thumb (at least on Heroku) if it *can* run longer than 2 seconds it needs to be in a background job.

An easy way to do that is with delayed_job. Here is the starting documentation on that:

[Active job basics](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html)